# Problem solving without for loop,but with vectorization (pandas dataframe) considering multi condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization

I have a dataframe like below :

```
id = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B']
workcycle = [0,4,5,100,140,0,5,20]
date = ['2022-01-01','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-02-04','2022-03-10','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-02-04']
failure_type=['A','B',None,'B',None,'A',None,None]
repair_type=[None,None,'Repair_Type_1',None,'Repair_Type_2',None,'Repair_Type_1','Repair_Type_2']
event=['failure','failure','Repair','failure','Repair','failure','Repair','Repair']
```

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDGC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDGC.png)]

This is dataframe about failure and repair of some machine. And there are multi failure type.

There are two criteria (workcycle and date) in parallel.

Let's think about just "workcycle"

I want to know about what is the main contributor of repair activity against failure.

My hypothesis :

Among failures which happened less than 30 workcycle before repair, if there are no same type of failure in 30 next workcycle after repair activity => wa can say that this repair activity is the main contributor of this failure.

For example, we can say that repair activity of workcycle 5 for machine id = A is the main contributor of failure solution of workcycle 0 for id =A.

However, I have one conditon :

If there are more than two repair activity after failure and difference of workcycle betwwen two repair is less than 30 workcycle, we will not treat it.

I want to have a result like below:

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WevxC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WevxC.png)]

I know how to do it using for loop, but I used too many for loop.

How can I use vectorlization using just np.where,loc, or others ?

Comment: Do you mind to share the code you wrote?

Comment: @stat_man it is not clear how the failure of row 0 differs from line 4?

Comment: @inquirer it has different id (line 0 => id A and line 4 => id B)

Comment: @stat_man the next failure must be with the same failure_type and less than 30 no matter what the id is. Right?

Comment: @inquirer actually, different id is just to show you that there are different equipement. It has to be considered separately. 
And Yes, it is about same failure type. If we had failure type A and repair after, failure B does not impact on our analysis. It is also has te be considered separately.

Comment: 1).As far as I understood you, 0 line workcycle < 30, failure_type = A. Subsequently, there is such a failure_type but with a different id, workcycle < 30, and it fits row 4. Right? Therefore row 0 is resolved. 2).Two repair operations, these rows follow one another or can there be other rows between them?

Comment: @inquirer thanks for your message. for 1), yes correct
for 2) actually this is about condition : 
If there are more than two repair activity after failure and difference of workcycle betwwen two repair is less than 30 workcycle, we will not treat it. We will not consider about type of repair activity and there are not other rows between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

id_ = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
workcycle = [0, 5, 100, 140, 0, 5, 20, 10]
date = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-02-04', '2022-03-10', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-02-04', '2022-02-04']
failure_type = ['A', None, 'B', None, 'A', None, None, None]
event = ['failure', 'Repair', 'failure', 'Repair', 'failure', 'Repair', 'Repair', 'Repair']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_, 'workcycle': workcycle, 'date': date, 'event': event, 'failure_type': failure_type})

df['is_resolved'] = 'Not resolved'
df['rep'] = True
df.loc[df[df['event'] == 'failure'].index, 'cs'] = 1
df['cs'] = df['cs'].fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Added one more line to trigger the condition: `more than two repairs`.

A column `'is_resolved'` is created with values `'Not resolved'`. `'rep'` column set to True (needed to exclude rows with more than 2 repairs). To be able to group `by group, 'cs'` is created (where 'failure' is first set to 1 and the rest to 0 and the cumulative sum is calculated).

```
def repair_func(x):
    aaa = np.where(len(x) > 2, (np.abs(df.loc[x.index, 'workcycle'].diff().values[1:]) < 30).all(), False)
    if aaa == True:
        df.loc[x.index[0] - 1, 'rep'] = False
        df.loc[x.index, 'rep'] = False


df[df['event'] == 'Repair'].groupby('cs')['event'].apply(repair_func)
```

Here, rows with `'Repair'` are selected from the `'event'` column. The result is `grouped by 'cs'` and any column is selected, in this case 'event'. `np.where` checks for more than two rows `'Repair'` . If the condition matches, the difference between the rows is calculated and the `condition < 30` is checked. If everything is met, then False is set for the entire group.

```
def failure_func(x):
    f = x.index[0] + 1
    aaa = df.loc[f:]
    bbb = np.where(f <= len(df), (aaa.loc[df.loc[f:, 'failure_type'] == x.values[0], 'workcycle'] < 30).any(), False)
    if bbb == True:
        df.loc[x.index, 'is_resolved'] = 'resolved'

df[(df['event'] == 'failure') & (df['rep'] == True)].groupby('cs')['failure_type'].apply(failure_func)

falure = df[df['event'] == 'failure'][['id', 'date', 'failure_type', 'is_resolved']].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here `'failure'` is selected from the 'event' column except `'rep' == False`. There is a grouping by 'cs' with a selection of the 'failure_type' column. In `'f'`, this is the next index after the selected row. `aaa` the selected dataframe by slice. In `np.where`, it is checked that the slice selection is within the indices: `f <= len(df)`. Next, the same 'failure_type' with `'workcycle' < 30` is searched for. If there is at least one such, then `'is_resolved' = 'resolved'` is set.

```
print(falure)
```

Output

```
  id        date failure_type   is_resolved
0  A  2022-01-01            A      resolved
1  A  2022-02-04            B  Not resolved
2  B  2022-01-01            A  Not resolved
```

Comment: Thanks a lot : just one last question. If we have more than 1 failure before repair, do you have any idea for this case ?

Comment: 1).each failure will be with the same 'id' and 'failure_type'? 2). And what should be in the 'is_resolved' column for each failure?

Comment: 1) for id, yes. But it can have different failure_type. 
2) is_resolved will be same for each failure. But If we have, it is interesting to have different repair type. 
I modifed input data and expected result.

Comment: Have you changed the dataframe data? I don't see your changes. Better add a new dataframe to the very bottom of your question.

Comment: I change it very recently

Comment: after row 1 there is the same failure_type row 3, but it has  workcycle > 30

Comment: Eventhough it is same failure_type, it has different workcycle (5 for line 1 and 100 for line 3)

Comment: Corrected the previous message. The first line has Not resolved because the next failure on line 3 has a workcycle greater than 30.

Comment: And failure_type on line 1 B, not A.